# Add autocomplete textbox to wpf built with powershell

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, autocomplete

How the heck can I make this happen. Combo Items var has all the truck names in it. I want to as I start typing into a text box in my WPF gui to auto complete against that array. I think that is the best way to achieve it. I really appreciate any help that can be provided or if there is a better solution. There are about 7500 names in the array/column I am trying to autocomplete.

```
$adOpenStatic = 3
$adLockOptimistic = 3
$objConnection = New-Object -comobject ADODB.Connection
$objRecordset = New-Object -comobject ADODB.Recordset
$objConnection.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = c:\Database\Gen3Data.mdb")
$objRecordset.Open("Select Truck_ID from Trucks", $objConnection,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)

$Mytrucks = $objRecordset.GetRows()
$objRecordset.Close()
$objConnection.Close()
$comboitems = @()
foreach($trck in $Mytrucks){$comboitems += $trck}
```